# What kinds of recurrence relations can be involved in a tabulation solution?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation, memoization

We all know F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) is an easy example. We can compute this by using DP.

But what about F(n) = F(n-1) + k, we could compute this by tabulation but would you still call it DP?

Also, are there any recurrences that cannot be computed using tabulation?

Is there a general theory surrounding the kind if recurrences that can be effectively computed using tabulation / DP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fast algorithm for F(n) has nothing to do with dynamic programming. Even thought he concepts are often muddled in teaching, memoisation (the technique of storing values of a function for later use) and dynamic programming (a certain kind of problems/recurrence relations) are different things. The connection is that memoisation is usually used to compute DP recurrences efficiently (in the "ideal", array form, although that's not necessary).

Comment: It seems clear that *any* recurrence can be calculated using memoisation. So what's the question? Is any recurrence suited to using a $k$-dimensional array as storage? (Probably not.) Are there recurrences for which memoisation does not provide increased efficiency? (Certainly yes.)

Comment: @Raphael Can you elaborate with examples for your comments "probably not" and "certainly yes"

Comment: 1) What if your parameters are not numbers (say, trees) or a few numbers scattered across a large range? The array only makes sense for integers and if you need most values.
2) Any recurrence with only one "recursive call" (e.g. factorial). Any recurrence which does cause the same set of parameters to appear often (e.g. Mergesort).
(Let me know if what I write here approaches an answer for your problem.)